# bounds google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, viewport, bounds, fitbounds

My Google maps API map zooms put to show all the markers added after a google places search. On a mobile map this can take a bit to load and as this app for cyclists I prefer to only show the results within the viewport. Most research I read indicates it is not possible to only return results within the view port. Is it possible for me to just keep the map bounds from changing after the markers are added? It would be great if it would just show me the markers added to the current bounds unless there is only one marker returned, then it should zoom to that marker. So searching for something general like pizza will show many pizza places in the current viewport without panning or zooming. Searching for a specific address will zoom to that marker even if it is outside the viewport.

```
 var input = document.getElementById('target');
 var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
 var bounds = map.getBounds();
 searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
 var markers = [];
 service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

 google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
     var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
     // alert("getPlaces returns "+places.length+" places");

     for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
       gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
     }

     gmarkers = [];
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

     for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
       var place = places[i];
       createMarker(place);
       bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     // if (markers.length == 1) map.setZoom(17);
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
     var bounds = map.getBounds();
     searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
   });

   ib = new InfoBox({});
```

Comment: That sounds easy enough to implement.  What issue are you having doing that?  Your code is currently written to zoom to show all the markers returned.

Comment: my primary issue is that this is my first project and I am still learning. As far as the code issue is concerned, I believe bounds.extend(place.geometry.location); is taking my empty bounds variable and giving it a lat and long that will display all of the markers. Then map.fitBounds(bounds) is actually using that bounds to resize the map to show all the markers. I have tried commenting out map.fitBounds and it seems to keep the map from moving but not always. Also the if statement only zooms if the marker added is outside the current bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question:

- it possible for me to just keep the map bounds from changing after the markers are added?

is yes. And as you say, involves removing the map.fitBounds.

To get the map to center and zoom on a single address, either use the geocoder for that (implement it separately) or check the number of results, if it is one, center the map on the result and if there is a suggested viewport in the result, use that to center and zoom the map [with map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport) I think].

Comment: I tried removing map.fitBounds and the function that changes the viewport if marker.length == 1. This works for some searches but the map bounds still changes some of the time. It seems that googles search box API is over riding my efforts to preserve the map viewport.

Comment: Your code is what is centering and zooming the map.  Post the code that is exhibiting the issue (a jsfiddle would probably be best).